# Adding Bugs with Repro Steps directly from Test Results

Tags: azure-devops

I've written some test scripts & run them using the test runner. This has worked great, but unfortunately I didn't record the bugs at the time, via the test runner (just failed the steps and added comments).

When I review the Test Run Results I can create a bug for the Dev Team, but the Repro Steps box doesn't get populated with anything meaningful (see image1).  I've spotted that the DevTeam can get to the test results via the 'Links' tab on the Bug, but it's a bit clunky:

[image: Image 1]

However if I'd created a bug direct from the test runner, the bugs Repro Steps box gets populated with exactly what the DevTeam needs:

[image: Image 2]

Does anyone know how/if I can generate the same nicely formatted test runner Repro Steps if I create a bug from the Test Results after testing? (I've got a few to do, so would prefer not to re-run the tests....)

Answer (score 0):

You can write some code that will read test run content and copy paste this in bugs because this is just html in content of bug.

The best approach would be to create bug, and later on link test run to created bug.
[image]